# How to know when to resolve referer

Tags: http, node.js

I was working on my server and encountered the need to implement the use of `request.headers.referer` When I did tests and read headers to determine how to write the parsing functions, I couldn't determine a differentiation between requests that invoke from a link coming from outside the server, outside the directory, or calls for local resources from a given HTML response. For instance,

Going from localhost/dir1 to localhost/dir2 using `<a href="http://localhost/dir2">` will yield the response headers:

`referer:"http://localhost/dir1" url:"/dir2"`

while the HTML file sent from localhost/dir2 asking for resources using local URI `style.css` will yeild:

`referer:"http://localhost/dir2" url:"/style.css"`

and the same situation involving an image could end up

`referer:"http://localhost/dir2" url:"/_images/image.png"`

How would I prevent incorrect resolution, between url and referer, from accidentally being parsed as `http://localhost/dir1/dir2` or `http://localhost/_images/image.png` and so on? Is there a way to tell in what way the URI is being referred by the browser, and how can either the browser or server identify when `http://localhost/dir2/../dir1` is intended destination?

Comment: What specific use are you planning to make of the `referer` value? How can there be a "collision" between it and the URL being requested?

Comment: @ebohlman By collision I mean by two different sets of url and referer  resolving to same address.